# How to code a custom button that will show youtube iframe, seek to start of video & then play

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently making a movie site that has a main splash screen with a "play trailer button".

When the play trailer button is pressed I would like the iframe to be shown & the video to  to be played.

I also need a close button that will pause the video, return to the beginning of the video and then hide the div.

```
<!--hidden by default-->
<iframe class="player">player goes here</iframe>

<!--shows 'player' and initiates start-->
<div id="play_button">Play</div>

<!--stops the video, returns to the start and hides the 'player'-->
<div id="close_button">Close</div>
```

I can easily manipulate the css for the video itself however I'm having difficulty using the youtube api.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to load your player via the api first so that it is loaded with the page.

**https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference**

Then you can set it to load in "PAUSE" state or load it with "cueVideoById".

Then have a floating dive with graphics and button placed over the video.

After that, you just need scripts that will play, hide div and put dive back again ( or what ever end result you want).

I think this should work for you.

Comment: Thank you.  Still having a bit of difficulty but I guess I'll need to look into this a little more before I can use it in projects.